# PhysX.sln doesn't compile (PhysX 3.4)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, physx

I just downloaded PhysX 3.4 on GitHub, but it seems like I can't compile PhysX.sln. I get a lot of errors like this :

> C1083 Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ....\SimulationController\src\ScTriggerInteraction.cpp)

I don't see why it doesn't compile... Any idea ? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 by the way.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got rid of these errors by changing the Windows SDK Version (in each PhysX.sln's project : Properties > General > Windows SDK Version). But now I have this error

> C1189  #error:  Visual studio 2017 prior to 15.5.1 is not supported because of a compiler bug.

Apparently NVIDIA is aware of this error, so I guess we just can't compile PhysX.sln on Visual Studio 15.5.1 and below for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that applies here.

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory

Those are headers from the C RTL, not C++. [C Run-Time Library Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59ey50w6%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

If you drop the `.h` from `<string.h>` and use `<string>` you will get the C++ string class header instead. The C++ replacement for `<string.h>` is `<cstring>`.

Also see: [Introducing the Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx)

Comment: Ok so I changed "stddef.h" to <cstddef>, but now the problem is in the file cstddef. I can't include "stddef.h" in it, so I still get the same error...